# Issue while installing and configuring Ambari

Tags: ambari

After successful completion of registering the target host,
I am facing the below issue please help me
[image]

i was trying to find out the users in target host,to remove them but i could not do it.

Answer (score 0):

At Last i Found it:
enter the below commands in the target host:

# userdel hive
   # userdel storm
   # userdel zookeeper
   # userdel oozie
   # userdel atlas
   # userdel ams
   # userdel falcon
   # userdel ambari-qa 
   # userdel flume 
   # userdel kafka 
   # userdel sqoop 
   # userdel yarn 
   # userdel mapred 
   # userdel hbase 
   # userdel knox
   # userdel tez
   # userdel accumulo